# JSON deserializer conflict with Spring Boot Starter Web and Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, jackson, spring-cloud-stream, spring-boot-actuator

I have a fairly simple Java app that listens to a Kafka topic for JSON messages.

These are the main dependencies and versions:

```
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.5.RELEASE'
...
set('springCloudVersion', "Hoxton.SR9")
...
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream'
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka'
```

The `application.properties` config that specifies the JSON format:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.listener-in-0.content-type = application/json
```

And the "core loop":

```
@Bean
public Consumer<Message<MyDataModel>> listener() {
    return message -> {
        ...
```

And it works like a charm. But now I'm trying to add a `/metrics` endpoint to the app, with the Actuator library:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
```

After adding these to `build.gradle`, **without changing anything in the code itself**, the consumer in the above snippet fails to deserialize the incoming messages, every field of the model object is *null*.

Clearly, the `spring-boot-starter-web` package overwrites the JSON handling mechanism that came with the `spring-cloud-stream` library, but I have no idea what to do. Experimented with excluding parts of the *web-starter* library and changing around the springBoot version, but no success yet.

Comment: This looks more like a regression of some sort. Can you please raise an issue - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues. You can include the link to this post to avoid duplicating your findings.

Comment: Added the issue there, but still hoping for a fix based on excluding something or somehow telling it which deserializer to use.

Comment: I have [replied to the issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/2111) and provided a full sample. I can not reproduce what you are describing. Perhaps there are other dependencies that are part of your classpath that mat get in the way, but so far it does not look like an actuator. As suggested in the issue comment, if you still believe there is a problem please provide a sample that we can use to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading the *springboot* version to **2.4.2** from **2.3.5.RELEASE**, and *spring-cloud* version to **2020.0.1** from **Hoxton.SR9** solved the issue for us.